# Nodejs controller sends the wrong data with Nodemailer

Tags: node.js, express, nodemailer

We are trying to create a contact form. the problem is that Node mailer's  from data shows my own while I set to the persons email who sends it. Here is the code:

```
app.post('/api/v1/contact', (req, res) => {
  var data = req.body;

  var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'Gmail',
    port: 465,
    auth: {
      user: '',
      pass: ''
    }
  });

  var mailOptions = {
    from: data.email,
    to: 'myemail@domain.com',
    subject: data.title,
    html: `<p>${data.email}</p>
          <p>${data.message}</p>`, 

...
...
```

data.email inside the HTML tag inside email body shows correctly the email of the sender while in the from field the same data.email shows my own email. It looks like I am sending email to me. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

That is not a bug. You simply not have access to send emails from someone else email address.

Comment: it's a contact form  where the person submits the email with his/her email. Then how will I know the sender for replying? Even WordPress allows such a thing.

Comment: I understand your problem but this will be not possible from a simple reason: imagine you put as "from" an email address of a very important person/company and then use that for some frauds. 

You can put the email address in subject and instead of reply, just send another email to that address as a response.

I don't know if there is another workaround for this ( Probably is ), i just told you why this is not working in your particular case.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of contact form in any website to make a communication from the customer to the site owner.

You can not make customer to send email using contact page.You can respond to their email.

So I will suggest you put customer email which you are getting in req.body.email parameter so that you can get to know who is trying to make contact.

It is better to give  Website admin /support email address in

```
auth: {
      user: '',
      pass: ''
    }
```

user attribute and the password for the same in pass attribute.

It is not the issue of nodemailer.